.Net Maui Error with app building #AMM0000
I have that error occurring each time I launch the project, and the error aims to AndroidManifest.xml file line

<activity 
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:theme="@style/Maui.SplashTheme"
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|density" 
android:launchMode="singleTop"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
>

ERROR
I am new to Maui.
AI says I need to add android:exported="true" line to android:name=".MainActivity, I've tried to add this but it erases that line.
I've also tried to clear and build the project again.

Could you provide detailed error message? And refer to this case: Building MAUI Android Failing.

Thanks for the reply I have sold it, just created new project and copied the code there. One thing I've learned that don't load useless packages and don't rename file names.

Well, as an answer:

.Net Maui Error with app building #AMM0000

Moving the code into a new project can resolve it. And notice that don't load useless packages and don't rename file names.

Thank you sir. Actually I did it, and then it worked. I am wondering why is it so complicated sometimes.
